# Create json array with keys and values dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I have a json array like this:

```
digitalDataProductsArray = [{
        'id': '',
        'name': '',
        'type': '',
        'subType': '',
        'accountType': '',
        'price': {
            'fullRetailPrice':'',
            'monthlyRecurringCharge':'',
            'dueToday':'',
            'dueMonthly':''
        },
        'attributes': {
            'lineNumber':'',
            'SOC':'',
            'SKU':'',
            'manufacturer':'',
            'color':'',
            'condition':'',
            'usingEIP':'',
            'EIPmonths':''
        }
    }];
```

And I have a json object(not complete object) like this:

```
{
    "productdetails" : 
    [
        {
            "DeviceId" : "456735",
            "Family" : "mobile phone",
        },
            "Features" : 
            [
                {
                    "Header" : "4.7 Retina Display",
                },
                {
                    "Header" : "5.5 Retina Display",
                }
            ],
        {
            "DeviceId" : "456736",
            "Family" : "Tablet",
        }
    ]
}
```

There are about 12 objects inside productdetails json obj.

Example:

```
0:
Object
1
:
Object
2
:
Object
3
:
Object
4
:
Object
5
:
Object
6
:
Object
7
:
Object
8
:
Object
9
:
Object
10
:
Object
11
:
Object
```

and each object contains this value:

```
{
    "DeviceId" : "456735",
    "Family" : "mobile phone",
}
```

I need to figure out the following:

1. I need to insert the values of above json object into the json array(digitalDataProductsArray )
2. The values of json object will be inserted into json array based on
   key mapping requirement below:

   - `id` should be mapped to `DeviceId`
   - `name` should be mapped to `Family`
3. so If there are 2 objects inside the json object, I need to create
   equal number of objects inside the json array with keys(such as `id`, `name` etc) and empty values

I tried the following but couldn't come to a solution.

```
app.service('populateProductService', function ($window) {
    var digitalDataProductsArray = $window.digitalData.events.products;

    digitalDataProductsArray = [{
        'id': '',
        'name': '',
        'type': '',
        'subType': '',
        'accountType': '',
        'price': {
            'fullRetailPrice':'',
            'monthlyRecurringCharge':'',
            'dueToday':'',
            'dueMonthly':''
        },
        'attributes': {
            'lineNumber':'',
            'SOC':'',
            'SKU':'',
            'manufacturer':'',
            'color':'',
            'condition':'',
            'usingEIP':'',
            'EIPmonths':''
        }
    }];
    console.log("digital data->events->products array: ", digitalDataProductsArray);
    console.log(digitalDataProductsArray[0].id);

    this.populateProductDetails = function (productDetails) {

        var apiProductsArray = productDetails.data.productdetails;
        console.log("API productdetails Array: ", apiProductsArray);

//        digitalDataProductsArray[0].id = apiProductsArray[0].DeviceId;

        for (var i = 0; i < apiProductsArray.length; i++) {
            digitalDataProductsArray.push(digitalDataProductsArray); //creates 1 object with 13 arrays 

//            console.log(i); //prints 11
//            digitalDataProductsArray[i].id = apiProductsArray[i].DeviceId;
//            digitalDataProductsArray[i].type = apiProductsArray[i].type;
        }
        console.log("printing digital-data product array: ", digitalDataProductsArray);
    };
});
```

This creates 1 object with 13 arrays and each array again has 1 object with 13 arrays and so on which is wrong. Unable to figure out logic for this.

Comment: Please provide a demo of this using fiddle, if you create the fiddle one could edit it to show the fix.

Comment: @Noctane ok I will try.

Comment: Your digitalProductsArray already contains two completely unrelated objects. How do you intend to deal with fishing around in that array to find the objects that I think you want to create as copies of that first object vs. the second object that seems to have no actual purpose relative to your question?